# php exec,imagemagick convert pdf to jpg return errors

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, exec

I've wrote a simple php file  **convert_pdf_to_single_continuous_long_image.php**, and it's content is:

```
$shell = '/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/bin/convert /Users/Bruce/www/pdf_files/sample.pdf -quality 500 -units pixelspercentimeter -density 500 -fill white -alpha remove -append /Users/Bruce/www/pdf_files/sample.png 2>&1';
@exec($shell,$output,$return_var);
var_dump($output);
```

if i ran the command below,it works!

`bash-3.2# php convert_pdf_to_single_continuous_long_image.php`

but if I ran it through browser, it failed and returns

```
array (size=1)
0 => string 'convert: no images defined 
/Users/Bruce/www/pdf_files/sample.png' @ 
error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.' (length=110)
who am I--->_www
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHigH.jpg)

both my nginx user and group are "_www", is that nginx no permission to read the pdf file? but the permission of the directory "/Users/Bruce/www/pdf_files" which contains the pdf file is：

```
drwxrwxrwx    8 Bruce  staff       272  4  3 16:43 pdf_files
```

I've google and find some similar questions, and some answer said that is because I didn't install ghostscript, but I do install it, And I put it's path to system PATH:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx7ZA.jpg)

And I also remove the ghostscript and then reinstall it by "brew istall ghostscript"

nginx:

```
bash-3.2# ps aux | grep nginx
nobody             299   0.0  0.0  2503496   1116   ??  S    11:44下午   
0:06.26 nginx: worker process
nobody             298   0.0  0.0  2503624   1740   ??  S    11:44下午   
0:03.38 nginx: worker process
nobody             296   0.0  0.0  2503496   1128   ??  S    11:44下午   
0:06.27 nginx: worker process
nobody             294   0.0  0.0  2503624   1896   ??  S    11:44下午   
0:02.97 nginx: worker process
root                68   0.0  0.0  2503496   4860   ??  Ss   11:44下午   
0:00.02 nginx: master process /usr/local/opt/nginx/bin/nginx -g daemon off;


bash-3.2# ps aux | grep php-fpm
_www             45743   0.0  0.1  2560356   9992   ??  S     1:48下午   
0:00.22 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config 
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
_www             45720   0.0  0.1  2560356  10288   ??  S     1:47下午   
0:00.49 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config 
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
_www               309   0.0  0.1  2560356  10540   ??  S    11:44下午   
0:01.94 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config 
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
root               107   0.0  0.0  2517076   7356   ??  Ss   11:44下午   
0:01.80 /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config 
/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
```

I'm sorry the Chinese word "下午" means p.m.

I've tried to set the user and group of php-fpm to root:wheel, but failed, it tells me that I can't ran php-fpm as root.

So I really don't know what's going on, I guess the problem is about permission.Hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: why your don't easily use [imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) php extension ?

Comment: Have you tried a simple convert on a pdf file in the same folder as the php code? e.g. convert sample.pdf sample.jpg Out of interest Version 7 of Imagemagick the preferred method is magick not convert. If you have installed Imagemagick with legacy? programs convert should still work.

Comment: thank you for your guys suggestion, I'll try it, but I still don't know why I can't run with exec

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues...

**Issue 1**

You appear to be using **homebrew** on a Mac. **homebrew** puts symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to the various versions of applications in the Cellar. The idea is that you use:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

and not

```
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.5-4/bin/convert
```

so that when you upgrade a package, you don't have to change all the version numbers.

**Issue 2**

When you checked the PATH, I think you did so as yourself, rather than checking the path of the user `_www`.

Comment: for Issue1:    


`thank you very much for your advice of using symbolic links in /usr/local/bin, I don't know this before.`

for Issue2:
  

`I tried to change the ownership and group of "/Users/Bruce/www/pdf_files" which contains the pdf file, but it turns out the same error!`
  

`bash-3.2# chown -R _www:_www pdf_files
bash-3.2# ls -l | grep pdf_files
drwxrwxrwx 8 _www _www 272 4 3 16:43 pdf_files`